# Excel randomly changes focus when selecting cell

Tags: excel, vba, focus, scrollbar

I have built a mapping tool with some VBA that show or hides some named rows based on specific named cells. It all works fine but I get a strange bug when I select some cells the view scrolls down to the bottom of my sheet and my cell is still selected. See gif screenshot. Very annoying to scroll back up to change my selected cell value.

[image]

As you see the scrollbar and view moves down unintentionally.

My code on the sheet is this:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Range("J:J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    
    
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Sprog")) Is Nothing Then
                 Call ChangeLanguage
    End If
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Basisform")) Is Nothing Then
                 Call ChangeSpecialist
    End If

    End If
    Call ChangeSpecialist
    
  End Sub
  
  Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
  
  '--------------drop down emner---------------------
  With Target
  'analyser
    If .Address = Range("spec_analyse").Address Then
      Select Case .Value
        Case ChrW(9658)
          .Value = ChrW(9660)
          Range("spec_analyse").Offset(1, 0).Select
        Case ChrW(9660)
          .Value = ChrW(9658)
        Case Else
          .Value = ChrW(9658)
      End Select
    End If
    'beregninger
    If .Address = Range("spec_beregninger").Address Then
      Select Case .Value
        Case ChrW(9658)
          .Value = ChrW(9660)
          Range("spec_beregninger").Offset(1, 0).Select
        Case ChrW(9660)
          .Value = ChrW(9658)
        Case Else
          .Value = ChrW(9658)
      End Select
    End If

  End With
  Call ChangeSpecialist
  
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  
  End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any event code?

Comment: Yes - if you mean code on the sheet that checks for any changes in certain named cells and named ranges

Comment: added code in the post

Comment: But this issue is caused by selecting cells, not changing them? Do you have any selection event on the sheet or workbook?

Comment: Yes. Added the code to the post

Comment: It would be better if you posted all relevant code up front rather than having to be asked. Is there anything else? In the selection event why are you selecting - that will cause the code to trigger again.

Comment: Sorry tried to shorten it for easier understanding. I change the code in the post. There is also code in modules that the events calls, but I think the problem is in the event part as you say. The reason I have both a change and selection change is that I have two situations I would like to check for: 1. if a cell value changes I want to show some extra rows. 2. The black triangles is a drop down that changes when you click on it and then show some extra rows and hides them again if clicked again. I guess this is the conflict, but hope that I can achieve it but optimzing the code.

Comment: The first thing to do is disable events before selecting a cell (btw selecting cells is rarely necessary and generally not advisable).

Comment: I had a similar effect. I had some controls at the top of the worksheet and used the SelectionChanged event. Beginning with Excel 2007, navigating with arrow keys got much slower. I've found out that the focus jumps to the controls and back to the cell at every cursor movement. But I didn't observe scrolling as in your case. Does the behaviour change if you move the Submit button to the top of the worksheet? Or if you replace it with a double-click event in a certain cell?